# How to get iframe instance from inside an friendly iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an iframe and a script that executes inside it as shown below

```
<iframe name="myframe" src="test.html">
    <script> <!--My script-->
      ..
    </script>
</iframe>
```

I want to get an instance of the iframe from inside the iframe. One way is to go to the parent page and access the iframe object as shown below

```
parent.document.getElementByID('myframe')
```

Is there any better way (any window or document attribute that points to the parent frame when its present) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use "window.frameElement;"
This is documented here:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_frameElement.asp

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to grab the iframe object right?

can't you just use a formal jQuery call of the iframe??:

```
$('iframe')
```

see this example: https://jsfiddle.net/79bnmcgb/3/

Comment: I want to get from inside the iframe. Your JS is on the page.